# only inner faces of 3D object are visible

Tags: three.js, blender

I have an object I made in Blender: [image: here] and when I render this object in Three.js, the faces of the object are transparent and only the inner side of the faces are visible: [image: here] Is there some setting I may have unknowingly turned on? I just want to get it back to normal like it is in Blender.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: inverting normals solved my issue. Maybe I had accidentally flipped them somewhere along the way.